# Showing a JSON with the following structure in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

Good afternoon

I recieve this JSON

```
{"id":130,"nif":"47812480B","name":"Bernat","cognoms":"Fernandez","file":"uploads\/fondo.jpg","birthday":"0000-00-00","presentacion":"presentacion","email":"bernat@gmail.com","password":"$2y$10$GfP1DYkTqyohjVzRcuuxaeKBSu7iJUBWJK6UDj7p681307uI6Ersq","idempresa":1,"id_poblacion":889,"id_online":0,"remember_token":null,"created_at":"2015-05-28 15:25:04","updated_at":"2015-05-27 15:25:04","municipio":{"id":889,"idprovincia":33,"poblacion":"Art\u00e9s","poblacionseo":"artes","postal":8271,"latitud":"41.798479","longitud":"1.954828"},"subastas":[{"id":16,"nombre":"HTC Wildfire","descripcion":"Descripcion","precio_salida":125,"cant_actual":125,"id_estado":0,"id_metode_envio":1,"id_metodo_pago":1,"id_creador":130,"id_ganador":125,"id_categoria":33,"id_adquirido":1,"data_inici":"2015-06-13","data_final":"2015-06-13","durada":1,"created_at":"2015-06-06 09:09:54","updated_at":"2015-06-06 09:55:49"}]}<p>34.884533408812</p> {"id":131,"nif":"263","name":"Lalo","cognoms":"Lelo","file":"uploads\/count.png","birthday":"0000-00-00","presentacion":"jejjsjsj","email":"vsdfsfaf@aasa.com","password":"$2y$10$QtrolUS9emCS7bfirsly9.JXt9AsYfAc.\/vA0iJCs47\/3g\/ypc8d6","idempresa":1,"id_poblacion":175,"id_online":0,"remember_token":"B1vEqdX8w42i7sLNvG201EArwSTrODe0DDzkVmjzj48ahMMV8oOLmzYRM5Mp","created_at":"2015-05-20 06:52:59","updated_at":"2015-06-06 08:35:13","municipio":{"id":175,"idprovincia":9,"poblacion":"Benej\u00fazar","poblacionseo":"benejuzar","postal":3390,"latitud":"38.083525","longitud":"-0.836494"},"subastas":[{"id":15,"nombre":"Nombre","descripcion":"Descripcion","precio_salida":142,"cant_actual":142,"id_estado":1,"id_metode_envio":1,"id_metodo_pago":1,"id_creador":131,"id_ganador":131,"id_categoria":33,"id_adquirido":1,"data_inici":"2015-06-18","data_final":"2015-06-17","durada":1,"created_at":"2015-06-06 00:00:00","updated_at":"2015-06-06 10:00:57"}]}<p>475.51158492016</p>
```

When I use the following foreach I show the information

```
@foreach ($subastas as $subasta)    
{{$subasta}}
@endforeach
```

Now I try to use the following code

```
@foreach ($subastas as $subasta)    
    @foreach ($subasta->subastas as $sub)   
        {{$sub}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And I recieve this error

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp3\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\prodcercanos.blade.php)
```

Any solution for this problem ?

The question is , how I can render the json in laravel ?

The controller to recieve the JSON

```
public function productoscercanos ($lat,$long){
        $subastas = Subasta::all();
        $categorias = Categoria::all();
        $provincias = Provincia::all();
        $cercanos = User::with(array('municipio', 'subastas'))->get();
        $coordA   = Geotools::coordinate([$lat,$long]); 
        $output = [];
        foreach ($cercanos as $p) {
            if(count($p->subastas)>0){
            $coordB   = Geotools::coordinate([$p->municipio->latitud,$p->municipio->longitud]);
            $distance = Geotools::distance()->setFrom($coordA)->setTo($coordB);
            $dis = $distance->in('km')->haversine();
            $output[$dis] = $p."<p>$dis</p>";
            }
        }       
        ksort($output); 
        return view('prodcercanos')->with('categorias',$categorias)->with('provincias',$provincias)->with('subastas',$output);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$json = (your json file);
$subasta = json_decode($json);`
 then you should be able to use the json as a object now.

Comment: Hello , I update the question , I recieve this JSON because I return the controller answer , It's not a file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is outputting exactly what is defined. First look at how the controller is building the array.

```
$output[$dis] = $p."<p>$dis</p>";
```

$p is a User model from the variable $cercanos, appending it to $dis results in it being converted into JSON and added to your output array which your view iterates and outputs.

It looks like you are trying to add the distance to the user and pass it on.

Instead use an [Accessor & Mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) to add an extra attribute to your model then pass on the $cercanos list to the view, from there you can render using a for each and grab the value.

```
@foreach($cercanos as $c)
   {{ $c->username }} {{ $c->dis }}
@endforeach
```

**Update**

Once you have added your accessor and mutator you will be able to sort using Collections built in method.

```
$cercanos->sortBy('dis');
```

Comment: But I need to sort by distance , for this reason I create the foreach and use ksort.

Comment: @jcsa collections (such as `$cercanos`) already have such a feature. [more details](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#collections)

Answer (score 0):

Try array syntax in the second foreach loop.

```
@foreach ($subasta['subastas'] as $sub)   
    {{$sub}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I try to use this but I show "Illegal string offset 'subastas'"